# Passing dataURL to href produces file with text 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, href, data-uri

I was given the task of removing certain non-printing characters from a .srt file and went about it the following way.
1) import file

2) read file as text

3) use RegEx to replace non-printing characters

4) convert text back into file and attach to href attribute in anchor tag for download.

Please review my approach.

However, the step of passing the dataURL to the href attribute seems to not be working.  My console.log statements are showing a dataURL but for some reason it is not being passed to the href attribute.  When I download the file and open it, it is a blank file that just says 'undefined'.

Please advise

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
  }

  uploadFile(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    if(file) {
      console.log(file);
      let textReplaced;
      let originalFileAsText;
      let output;
      //var aTag1 = document.getElementById('original');
      var aTag2 = document.getElementById('modified');
      const reader1 = new FileReader();
      reader1.onload = function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.result);
        originalFileAsText = reader1.result;
        textReplaced = originalFileAsText.replace(/\r\n(?=\r\n)(?=^\d+$)/g, /\n/);
      }
      reader1.readAsText(file);


      output = new File([textReplaced], "", {type: "text/plain"})
      console.log(output);
      const reader2 = new FileReader();
      reader2.onload = function(event) {
        console.log("result --->", reader2.result);
        console.log("eTargetRes--->",event.target.result);
        aTag2.href = reader2.result;
        console.log(aTag2.href)
      }
      reader2.readAsDataURL(output);

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="file"
        name="og"
        onChange={this.uploadFile}/>
        <div id="text-container" style={{"display" : "flex", "flexDirection" : "row", "justifyContent" : "space-evenly"}}>
          <a href="" download="original_file.srt" style={{"width":"200px"}} id="original" name="original" alt="original"> uploaded file </a> 
          <a href="" download="modified_file.txt" style={{"width":"200px"}} id="modified" name="modified" alt="modified"> modified file </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/reergymerej/pqb4y7sm/35/) seems to work just fine.  Keep in mind `FileReader` does [its work asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).  You should wait to set up the 2nd reader until the first one is done.

The console logging is misleading in this case.  Here is a cleaned up version of the uploadFile method for consideration.  It's a bit side-effect-y, but it is simpler and works.

```
 uploadFile(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    if(file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      const setResultAsHref = (event) => {
        const aTag2 = document.getElementById('modified');
        aTag2.href = event.target.result;      
      }

      const convertResultAndSetHref = (event) => {
        const originalFileAsText = event.target.result;
        const textReplaced = originalFileAsText.replace(/\r\n(?=\r\n)(?=^\d+$)/g, /\n/);
        const output = new File([textReplaced], "", {type: "text/plain"})
        event.target.onload = setResultAsHref
        event.target.readAsDataURL(output);
      }

      reader.onload = convertResultAndSetHref;      
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  }
```